# Can I see which tags I created?

Tags: support, status-declined, tags

Is it possible to see which tags I created?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No

This same exact feature was [requested on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82/184498). It was then subsequently marked [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) by Jeff.

There is a limited work-around though. If you have the *Taxonomist* badge, which is awarded for tags with more than 50 questions, it will tell you which tag you earned the badge for.

Comment: I wanted to see how close to the badge I was :(

Comment: @AlexChamberlain I would say to use the Data Explorer but there is only monthly-data dumps and it's for graduated sites only.